# Subtract one table from another

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables with two different select statements. These tables contain only one column. I would like to subtract the rows from `table2` from rows in `table1` only once. In other words: I would like to remove only one occurence, not all.

table1:

```
apple
apple
orange
```

table2:

```
apple
pear
```

result:

```
apple
orange
```

Comment: This is not as simple as it may seem. Which dbms do you use? Different dbms handle this differently.

Comment: The dbms I am using is MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically FYI If `A={A,A,O},B={A,P}` then `A-B` is logically

```
select * from t1 except select * from t2
```

try this !

```
create table #t(id varchar(10))
create table #t1(id1 varchar(10))
insert into #t values('apple'),('apple'),('orange')
insert into #t1 values('apple'),('pear')


select * from
(
select *,rn=row_number()over(partition by id order by id) from #t
except
select *,rn1=row_number()over(partition by id1 order by id1) from #t1
)x
```

## [SEE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17594)

Comment: This will return only `orange` as EXCEPT gets rid of duplicates.

Comment: Yes, your edited code works just like I wanted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for an Oracle dbms. The trick is to number records per fruit, so to get apple 1, apple 2, etc. Then subtract the sets to stay with apple 2 whereas apple 1 was removed for instance. (The row_number function needs a sort order which is not important for us, but we must specify it for syntax reasons.)

```
select fruit
from
(
  select fruit, row_number() over (partition by fruit order by fruit)
  from table1
  minus 
  select fruit, row_number() over (partition by fruit order by fruit)
  from table2
);
```

Comment: And now you want the same for MySQL? Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support such functions. You will have to work with variables that you set and reset within your query. Here is a link where they show you how to do this: http://www.explodybits.com/2011/11/mysql-row-number/. There are certainly examples in stackoverflow, too.

Comment: Thank you but I rather switched to Oracle. It is easier that way since this is a school project and the exact dbms is not specified.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you would be able to delete the records through a single SQL query:

According to me, you will need to connect the database to a programming language and will need to write an algorithm like this:

```
for(all records in table2)
{
    if(record present in table1)
    {
        delete from table1 where record = (record in table2) limit 1;
    }
}
```